# Mocking help?I can't find what's the problem

Tags: mocking, nmock

I have an interface definded like this:

```
public interface IDatabase{ void Get<TTypeToFetch> ();}
```

and when I try to do: 
`Mockery mockery = new Mockery();
IDatabase db = mockery.NewMock<IDatabase>();`

I get the following error:

> System.TypeLoadException:  System.TypeLoadException: Signature of the body and declaration in a method implementation do not match

What is wrong? (I am using Visual Studio 2008 with nmock2) 
Please could everyone give me an answer, I have  to finish this soon.
Thanks,
Luisa

Comment: Removed tag "rhino-mocks" because this question has nothing to do with the mocking framework Rhino.Mocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may be a problem with NMock, possibly even a bug. The type `IDatabase` is not generic, so when you invoke `Get<T>`, different `T`s could be used at runtime. But when NMock is generating the mock, it doesn't appear to understand that this is the case, and kablammo -- each method signature is different, depending on the type parameter supplied.

Try doing this instead:

```
public interface IDatabase<T> {
  void Get<T>();
}
```

Also, shouldn't the type of `Get` be `T`, not `void`?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exception with my own interface. When i change interface to be public everything runs ok.